# Pop Out Calendar

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on my Final Year Project at University.

For this project I have to build an adaptive website. And one of the adaptive features that I am going to include date adaptions. So when the user clicks a different date the website will change its contents and theme to that date.

e.g. if a user clicks 25th December, It will be a christmas theme.

I currently have a button with the text 'Change Date'. I want to make a pop out calendar, which appears when the button is clicked.

Ideally I would like to use PHP, but I understand this may not be ideal.

What I am looking for is any hints, tips, useful links that may be of use to me and any solutions that any one is willing to share.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Any Ideas on how I could code this myself or tutorials would be nice, but other suggestions welcome. Even any alternatives welcomed. Thanks.

EDIT 2: Also , the calendar needs to be able to adapt. i.e. if the user is visiting from china it needs to allow for differences in time between various locations.

Comment: @wimvds, haha that link has an animation of someone typing in your query and then it goes to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done UI for several years, I'd recommend doing this interaction on the front end, so you could use any server-side language to support what you're doing.  My personal preference for a front-end framework is Jquery due to its great documentation, adherence to proper standards, and simplicity.

For the calendar, Jquery has a native [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin to do popup calendars that I believe are the industry standard today.  They populate standard HTML text input fields that can then be passed to PHP via a submit (or via Jquery's ajax) to do with what you like.  Depending on the setup of your page, it could be a matter of one line of code to accomplish a well-designed, interactive popup calendar.

As for changing themes, [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) (part of Jquery UI) is absolutely awesome.  I use it in all my online applications.  When my company private labels a site, I can simply change one folder of graphics and one CSS file and my entire site's color scheme has changed, automatically.  You can even change on the fly with some simple syntax.  It's fast, clean, and gracefully degrades to support legacy browsers.  If you dig into the markup, you can actually use themeroller to theme any website, so when making a change every part of the site changes accordingly.  In my mind, you can't possibly go wrong with this method.

Good luck.

Comment: I have used the jQuery datepicker (someone made a timepicker too!) and I love it. It's loaded with features.

Comment: Pritty close to giving you 100 bounty for this but I was wondering if you could help me with one more thing! how customisable is the Jquery UI plugin?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to customize?  You can re-style CSS for look/feel, and chain behaviors together to get specific actions.  Give me more details of what you're looking for and I'll certainly point you in the right direction.

Comment: i would want to customise it so that it appeared on the click of a button, also i would like to customise it so that if a users Browser Region was different it would adjust to allow for time variations between regions

Comment: Ryan, it's very easy, both with pre-done tuts as well as by custom-rolling your solution.  This will show you how to trigger calendar with a button: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger.  I'm confused on the time variations, though--a calendar doesn't take into account hour variations.  Perhaps you're looking for something like this:  http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/  But the disconnect is how to know where they're from (sensing via browser isn't always reliable) to set a particular timezone.